# Bootstrap4: modal rendering issue with zoomed in body

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use a Bootstrap html page with body zoomed in at 90%.. The Bootstrap modal is showing spaces from right and bottom..
To show the issue i am putting a basic html page with modal at body 90% zoom..

When you click on the open modal you will see spaces from right and bottom for modal..How do we render modal with not extra spaces with body zoom 90%..Desired output is modal blur background should cover the whole screen.. and modal body should be in center of x axis as if zoom of 90% and 100% are same except the zoom 90% is small font

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="zoom:90%;">

<div class="container">
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a desired output?

Comment: desired output is modal blur background should cover the whole screen.. and modal body should be in center

Answer (score 7, accepted):

class .modal-backdrop is using 100vh & 100vw and since we applied 90% zoom, 100vh corresponds to 90% of the screen height;  100vw corresponds to 90% of the screen width;

**solution**: override this class with `width: 100%; height: 100%;`

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body style="zoom:90%;">

  <div class="container">
    <h1> with zoom 90%
    </h1>
    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            Modal body..
          </div>
          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```